# Appfog error “Error (JSON 500): not found”

Tags: paas, appfog

When I update my site content to appfog using af update [appname] returns an error like these

```
Uploading Application:
```

Checking for available resources: Error (JSON 500): 
500 Intern...

Any body have idea about these error which is caused by Appfog PaaS server

Comment: I too got that just now :( ...i mailed them though too know what is causing it ...some problem with their server only cause earlier it was working fine

Answer (score 2):

try to issue `af login` command again,then try to update,it worked for me

Comment: Actually it was the error for AppFog Server on that day only.Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

They had a problem 5-6am GMT in the AWS EU region, looks like a knock on effect. Assuming your apps are on this server then it's a problem with Appfog. https://console.appfog.com/ is also down.

Follow them on Twitter for service updates; http://twitter.com/appfogstatus